# How to put value from an object inside an array into a flatlist React Native

Tags: arrays, react-native, object, flatlist

so I have this array:

```
  let Reviews = [
    {
      name: "Tibo Mertens",
      review: "Very nice model",
    },
    {
      name: "Quintt Adam", 
      review: "I like the car",
    },
  ];
```

And a Flatlist:

```
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={Reviews}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          <View>
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
          </View>;
        }}
      ></FlatList>
    </View>
```

Where you see {item.name} I want to display the names of the objects in the flatlist. But nothing is showing, the value is undefined. How do I get the right values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

1. You are not returning the `View` in `renderItem`.
2. You having a semi-colon on the end of the `View` in `renderItem` - You should remove that.
3. `FlatList` should be self-closing.

```js
<View>
  <FlatList 
    data={Reviews}
    renderItem={({ item }) => 
      <View><Text>{item.name}</Text></View>
    }
  />
</View>
```

To note, the above is an [implicit return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body) and is an alternative to the following:

```js
renderItem={({ item }) => { 
  return <View><Text>{item.name}</Text></View>
}}
```